# ODBC driver not loaded (want to connect qt5.6 with sql server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, qt, opencv

```
QString servername = "AFGHAN-PC";
QString dbname = "try";
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setConnectOptions();

//  QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL Native Client};SERVER=%1;Database=%2;UID=sa;PWD=;").arg(servername).arg(dbname);

QString dsn = QString("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%1;Database=%2;Trusted_Connections=Yes;").arg(servername).arg(dbname);

db.setDatabaseName(dsn);

if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() <<"Openned!";
    db.close();

}
else
{
    qDebug() <<"Error = " <<db.lastError().text();

}
```

problem:

```
QSqlDatabase:ODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase:available drivers:QSQLITE QMSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

i already set my odbc driver in odbc data source and installed odbc driver for sql 2012.
im using.
windows 8.1 32bit OS.
QT creator 5.6
SQL Server 2012

Comment: You need to build the driver http://seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows

Comment: @Ahmad Afghan, is your Database connected to same machine ? or you are connecting over TCPIP .. what is `servername = "AFGHAN-PC";` is it a host name ?

Comment: @MohammadKanan that would give you a different error. By default QT doesnt have MYSQL drivers. The best bet is to download the orcale MYSQL connector as this does it all

Comment: @GPPK, MYSQL ..!!! the code is using QODBC towards MS SQL Server ?!

Comment: It's trying to, but Im pretty sure it doesn't have any drivers behind it to actually connect to the database. IMO this isn't a database configuration/access issue. Could be wrong though which is why I haven't posted an answer

Comment: @GPPK, I have had similar problem, the QODBC would not load IF the connection string is not correct ..

Comment: @MohammadKanan. yes . the database is already connected to the same machine."AFGHAN-PC" is local server name. i created a database in Ms sql server.

Comment: @AhmadAfghan, Ok, have you confgiured QSL server over TCPIP? can the server accept connection with TCPIP

Comment: @Mohammad Khanan ! but i dont know how to configure sql server over TCPIP. if any link?

Comment: @Mohammad Khanan ! i have configured sql server over TCPIP with the help of this link.     https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port   the server connected connection with TCPIP easily.

Comment: but above configuration did not solve qt and sql server connectivity problem.it still giving previous error. what to do?